# Direction of induced Electric fields

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In my text book there was a question :

A loop(charged) is lying in a Cylindrical region with magnetic field B . if the  field is turned off instantly, the find the change in angular velocity of the loop.

Now I was able to get an answer by assuming that an impulsive non conservative electric field is generated which is along the loop at all places.

But I am unable to understand why the electric field is circular ? ( and even if its circular then why along the loop only ?  why not a circle with some other center ?)

As far as I know , in order to prove that an Electric field is induced we say that the induced current is developed in a wire by Faraday's law and hence an Electric field must exist. But we could have taken any other shaped conductor. Would that change the direction of induced Electric field ?

Also does the cylindrical region play any role here ?

Comment: Have you learned Maxwell's equations?

Comment: No , i have not. I am a high school student.

Comment: If that's the wording of the question in your textbook, I think you should try to get hold of another textbook.